# Disable url change navigation or direct page access in Angular 7 without authguard?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, url, url-routing

Hi I am looking for a method or suggestions that if user change url to access to different page like this [image]

it will restrict the user and user redirect to same page, is there any method to do without Authguard or without using any Modules ?

my stackblitz project which  is not working

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v7g3xa?embed=1&file=app-routing.ts&view=editor)

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: One thing you can do is - creating a service that looks for every route change and restrict routing for specific url and navigating back to previous route

Answer (score 3):

when user changes his url by hand your application will be unloaded and loaded again. 
you can do some hacks with javascript like write url on unload, and then return it back on load

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(e) {
  localStorage.setItem("appUnloading", JSON.stringify({time: Date.now(), url: location.pathname}));
};
.....
export class GuardForAllRoutes {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  canActivate() {
    const appUnloadingState = localStorage.getItem("appUnloading");
    let time, url;
    if(appUnloadingState) {
      {time, url} = JSON.parse(appUnloadingState);
    }
     if(Date.now() - time < 10000) { //let say your page will be loaded for no more that 10 seconds
        return this.router.parse(url); // this won't work on old angular versions. use router.navigate instead
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: Where i need to put this code to works **globally**  in router.ts? or should i need to put in every ts file also it shows **cannot find time**  .

Comment: you can put event listener in app component on init hook, and attach guard to your root route

Comment: as you said i put **CanActivate** function in routing.module but still getting error `ERROR in app-routing.module.ts(72,20): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'time'.
app-routing.module.ts(73,19): error TS2339: Property 'router' does not exist on type 'AppRoutingModule'.`

Comment: @Andei but now it gives error `ERROR in app-routing.module.ts(74,19): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.` here is link for my app-routing.module.ts  [link](https://codeshare.io/5z1qAN)

Comment: Does it works in your local system because your **new updated code has error** `ERROR in app-routing.module.ts(19,19): error TS2449: Class 'ForbidRedirectByHandGuard' used before its declaration.
 .`

Comment: the correct way would be to place this class in another file, import it and use as a guard. usually examples provided are not full and it is considered that user knows these small skipped features.

Comment: apologies andrei as i am new so i am unware about this so as you said first i need to make a new file and import that file here right?

Comment: hey Andrei i just uploaded my project on stackblitz and did everything as you said please check once [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v7g3xa?embed=1&file=app-routing.ts&view=editor)

Answer (score 0):

The `**` path in the last route is a wildcard. The router will select this route if the requested URL doesn't match any paths for routes defined earlier in the configuration. This is useful for displaying a "404 - Not Found" page or redirecting to another route.

app.module:

```
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'hello', component: HelloComponent },


  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent } <---
];
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,

    ), FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, PageNotFoundComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ibrovt?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Hope it helps!

Comment: I need to return the user to the previous state rather than page not found whenever he is changing url manually

Comment: @UtsavUpadhyay, Did you get any solution? I have same issue.