# Angular restrict route direct access

Tags: angular, typescript

I have several routes defined from the Routes module. Everything works fine, and when I type the route in the borwser I am able to traverse through the pages.

However, what I want to do now is to not make any user access the route `person/createcourse`directly, but go through the route `course`.

This means the page `person/createcourse` is only accessible if the user is in the `course` page. How can I make this change.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:"" , component:HomePageComponent , pathMatch:"full"},
  {path:"course" , component:CourseComponent, canActivate:[ActGuardService]},
  {path:"person/listcourse" , component:CreateListComponent, canActivate:[ActGuardService]},

];
```

Comment: I guess you are looking for [nested routes](https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes)

Comment: I did implement the way you suggested, that's nested routes. However, I am still able to navigate via the URL. I want to prevent this as well. Do you know of a solution ? @robert

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59982359/2050306) can help